# Deploy Cordova app to a Windows Phone 8.1 device from Windows 10

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm trying to deploy my Cordova app to a WP 8.1 device from Windows 10.
For this, I'm executing `cordova run --device -- --phone`.

However, this command fails with an error message that `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\AppDeploy\AppDeployCmd.exe` is missing.
I manually checked and found out there is a `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools` directory with some contents, but no `AppDeploy` inside.

The next steps I took were:

- Change my VS 2015 installation and make sure everything related to WP is checked
- Install VS 2013 and do the same as above
- Install all WP 8.1 related items from [here](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/sdk-archive) (development tools, emulators)

After all these steps, the Application Deployment tool is still not available.

What am I doing wrong, i.e. what else do I need to install?

**Update:**

Error message:

> ERROR: App deployment utilities: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\AppDeploy\AppDeployCmd.exe", not found.  Ensure the Windows SDK is installed.

For what it's worth, building works, and I can open the generated project in Visual Studio and deploy from there without any problems.

Comment: Does `cordova build` work? Can you open the VS Project from your cordova with Visual Studio and build it?

Comment: Yes, I can build, then open the project in VS and deploy to my device from there. Apparently, VS studio doesn't use `AppDeployCmd.exe` for deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I found a solution myself:*

On my machine, I'm using two drives, and SSD (`C:`) and a hard drive (`Z:`). Windows and some programs are installed on `C:`, but due to limited space, many programs are located on `Z:`.

For some reason, `AppDeployCmd.exe` was located on `Z:` under the same path as it was expected on `C:`, i.e. `Z:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\AppDeploy\AppDeployCmd.exe`.
Apparently, parts of the SDK were installed on `Z:` and others on `C:`, even though I though this couldn't be customized in the wizard.

Anyway, I just copied the `AppDeploy` directory to it's dedicated position on `C:` and deploying works now.